# Google's Opinion on Javascript Page Refresh

Tags: google, refresh

I was wondering if anyone knows Google's view on this.

My company has a homepage that features a lot of 3rd parties on it and it needs to inform customers which ones are currently online, which aren't, and which are currently busy. Because this constantly changes, we have the homepage refresh to show the most relevant and up-to-date content to our users.

I'm not using a meta refresh element in the http-equiv parameter to do this. Instead I have this js element to refresh the page:
window.setTimeout("refreshPage()", 120000);

I just want to know whether people think Google might consider this a violation of the content guidelines or not. Or if it's not an outright violation, then at least if Google frowns on this or not. It doesn't redirect the user to a different page or anything, just refreshes the page so that they can see the most relevant content.

Comment: Why not use something like AJAX to update the content dynamically? I don't think neither Google, users or developers consider it good practice nor a good user experience if you force things upon the user. I.e refresh the page without the users permission.

Comment: Idealy you want to let google know that your web content is constantly updating, so ajax is probably the best way forward.

Comment: I have seen things that mention AJAX as being a good alternative. I would just have to be something I could convince the programmers to work on. If you know of a good place to research more about it so I can approach them from a stronger position, please share.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax would be the proper solution, but in the mean time, if there is no Google ads on your pages, then Google won't frown.